# How can I implement a search using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some elements:

```
<p>Windows Phone 7</p>
<p>Windows Phone 7.5 "Mango"</p>
<p>Phone Windows 7</p>
```

1. If I search for `Phone 7` it should return all results.
2. If I search for `7 Windows` it should return all results.
3. If I search for `"Phone Windows"` it should return only the last element.

Basically the user will input some text in an `input` and I want to implement `AND` and `OR` with Regex.

How can I implement this?

Comment: And each element to an array, loop through the array and if an element contains the search string, add it to a `results` array, then return the `results` array.

Comment: You have to define the rules in more detail.  For example, how is the code supposed to know that `7 Windows` is not order dependent, but `Phone Windows` is?  A word match would make all three be a match for `Phone Windows`.  A string match would not match `7 Windows` for anything.  We need more logic rules.  Also, are you only matching whole words?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ without quotes it should match all. With quotes none should match.

Comment: Is this close? http://jsfiddle.net/KUYcA/

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions? If the rules are as simple as you state, then you'd be better off just using `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to parse your find text and construct a regular expression from the parts.  First, find all the phrases with `/"[^"]+"/g` and strip off the quotes.  Next, remove the phrases from the find text and find all the remaining words by splitting on whitespace: `/\s+/`.  Then concat your two arrays and join to create a new regular expression where each search term is wrapped in positive lookahead syntax: `(?=.*SearchTerm)`.  Finally, use that regular expression to test whether the given text matches.  Here's a search function that does that:

```
function search(find, within) {
    find = find.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&");
    var phrase = /"[^"]+"/g;
    var phrases = find.match(phrase) || [];
    phrases = $.map(phrases, function(s) {
        return s.replace(/"/g, "");
    });
    var words = find.replace(phrase, "").split(/\s+/);
    var terms = words.concat(phrases);
    var searchExpression = new RegExp("(?=.*" + terms.join(")(?=.*") + ").+", "i");
    return searchExpression.test(within);
}
```

Tie it into your page with some jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchButton").click(function() {
        var searchText = $("#searchInput").val();
        $("p").removeClass("matchesSearch").filter(function() {
            return search(searchText, $(this).text());
        }).addClass("matchesSearch");
    });
});
```

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/DVxem/

**Edit:** Works here too, with the fix to escape regex metacharacters: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/DVxem/3/

Comment: I was about to post the solution I implemented, it is very similar to yours. Fantastic. My solution to build the regex is `var p = text.match(/"([^"]+)"|([^ ]+)/gi);` and `var re = new RegExp(p.join("|").replace(/"/g, ""), "gi");`.

Comment: -1 Why would you want to build a `RegExp` object if you are looking for constant strings? Not only it hurts efficiency, but this will not work correctly if any of your search terms contain regex metacharacters (the first to come to mind is `.`)

Comment: @BrunoLM http://jsfiddle.net/DVxem/2/ Search for `7.`. Oooops... Pronto, quebrei o seu sistema de busca.

Comment: @NullUser - Why would you want to use a loop when you could just use a single RegExp?  Escaping regex characters is a trivial task - see: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/DVxem/3/.  I'll update my answer.  Really, what is the problem here?  Stylistic preference?

Comment: I removed the downvote, but I just think it's fundamentally wrong to use regex if you are looking for constant strings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [skeleton code](http://jsfiddle.net/KUYcA/) by [IAbstractDownvoteFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/724626/iabstractdownvotefactory):

```
var search = $('#text').val(),
    filter;

if (search.match(/^"(.+)"$/)) {
    search = search.match(/^"(.+)"$/)[1].toLowerCase();
    filter = function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1;
    };
} else {
    var words = search.split(" ");
    filter = function() {
        for (var i=0; i != words.length; i++) {
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i]) == -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

$('p').css({color: 'black'}).filter(filter).css({
    color: 'red'
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kVUJj/3/**